# Run time tracing method execution - spring-cloud-sleuth provides

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

spring-cloud-sleuth provides way to trace method execution with [@NewSpan](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/multi/multi__managing_spans_with_annotations.html#_creating_new_spans)

As it is annotation it is not feasible to add annotation on all methods of project.

Also, in production environment we only need to trace the method execution time once we find latency in execution.

Is there any way to enable tracing for Method calls at run time without restarting  application?

Comment: Your question is very specific. If you can break it down into simpler questions and explain the context thoroughly, that should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing comes out of the box for such an approach. What you can do though, is to register your own implementation of the `SpanReporter`. In that implementation, you could retrieve the duration for a `Span` and then, depending on its value, either send it to Zipkin or not (or do something else about it).